# How to pass value from one jsp to other through window.open

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting gra value from one.jsp as follows

```
<script language="javascript">
function gotoAddPanelAction(elem)
{ 
var st=elem.value;
if(st!="")
{
Popup=window.open('SelectInterviewPannel2.jsp?gra='+st,'Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes',400,400);
}
else
{
validateForm(document.frm);
}
}
</script>
```

I am retriving the value in SelectInterviewPannel2.jsp as follows

```
<td width="60%" class="txt-lable">
 <Select name="grade" ><option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <%
String gra = request.getParameter("gra");
 if(gra.value=="Level 1") {
%>
<option value="E1">E1</option><option value="E2">E2</option><option value="E3">E3</option><option value="E4">E4</option></select>
<% } else  {%>
 <option value="M1">M1</option><option value="M2">M2</option></select>
<% } %>
 </td>
```

My problem is in SelectInterviewPannel2.jsp if statement is not executing . I am getting only drop down box for select with no values in it.

Comment: Where's the integer with a comma? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If gra parameters does not exist , `request.getParameter("gra")` will return `null` and comparing using `if(gra.equals("Level 1"))` will throw out  Null pointer exception  . So you can try to use `if("Level1".equals(gra))` to avoid the Null pointer exception when the gra parameters does not exist

Answer (score 5):

```
 if(gra.value=="Level 1") {
```

Shouldn't you use `equals()`  method for string comparission

**Some Suggestions:**

- [Don't use java code on jsp.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @Akshatha Can't you see this[NULL handling] thing taken care in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699249/how-to-pass-value-from-one-jsp-to-other-through-window-open/5699276#comment-6512459) comment of mine

Answer (score 4):

First of all why this title: **how to remove comma in integer in java** it does not match with your question.

**As an answer:**

Instead of this

```
if(gra.value=="Level 1")
```

use this

```
if(gra.equals("Level 1"))
```

In java `==` **Compares references, not values** and to compare values of string you should use `.equals(str)`.

Comment: well I recommend you to go for JSTL , but still if you want to continue with this java code in jsp then `String gra = request.getParameter("gra");
 if("Level 1".equals(gra)) {` should work